# Is it ok to execute undefined callback in event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

I am writing a code that performs a function on click on a set of elements. It has a revalidate function. This revalidate function is fired on window resize. It checks if certain conditions are not fulfilled after resize then nothing should be done on click on body. This is an oversimplified version. Code:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // do something
}

var myCallback = myFunction;

$(".myClass").on("click", myCallback);

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(//certain conditions are met) {
        myCallback = undefined;
    }
    else {
        myCallback = myFunction
    }
});
```

I know I can use jquery `off` to detach the handler. But the actual code is more complex. It is a plugin like code where if I click event is bound in certain conditions inside the plugin definition. If I use `off` then to use `On` again appropriately I might have to run the whole plugin code once again; that beats the purpose of `revalidate` function. So,

Is it ok to execute undefined callback in event listeners?

P.S: I have been also reading about `jQuery.noop`. Seems like it's the exact situation to use that.

Comment: `undefined` is not executable so I wouldn't recommend it. You can always set it to an empty function: `myCallback = function () {};`

Comment: i mean... did you even try? that would pretty quickly tell you if you can. A better option though would be to simply have a conditional inside of myFunction.

Comment: @KevinB Yes I tried and it works fine.

Comment: The variable `myCallback` is not evaluated every time the event occurs, it's evaluated when you assign the event handler. Reassigning `myCallback` doesn't make the handler undefined.

Comment: @KevinB Probably not a bad idea to get a second opinion. Browser behavior can be vastly different and testing all possible options might not be reliable or feasible. Someone here may be able to cite a spec that could answer more definitively or suggest some possible pitfalls.

Comment: @CollinD Sure, but info on the results from trying what he's thinking about doing would be useful within the question. (you know, like the fact that re-assigning to undefined doesn't actually stop the function from running)

Comment: @Barmar Hmm... you are right. The original `myCallback` is still fired even after `myCallback = undefined`

Comment: @KevinB I totally agree. I was getting at why the actual question posed is a-ok, regardless of the failed implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't call an undefined function, because the variable `myCallback` is only evaluated when you bind the event handler, not every time the event occurs. To have the question you ask, it would have to be the following code:

```
$(".myClass").on("click", function(e) {
    myCallback.call(this, e);
});
```

When `myCallback` is set to undefined this will get an error, complaining that `undefined` is has no property `call`. What you should write is:

```
$(".myClass").on("click", function(e) {
    if (myCallback) {
        myCallback.call(this, e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Also is it ok to do the following: `$("body").on("click", undefined);` Though I don't actually need it. I am asking just out of curiosity.

Comment: I suspect jQuery will simply ignore it, because it checks the types of its arguments to determine which form of the function you're calling, and that doesn't match any of the signatures.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this,

```
$(".myClass").on("click", myCallback);
```

A reference to `myCallback` function is sent. When reassigning it, the callback (reference) sent to the `on` function will not be changed.

What you probably wanted to do is something like this

```
$(".myClass").on("click", function(){ myCallback(); });
```

Now when `myCallback` is `undefined`, you'll get an error saying it's not a function. You could assign it an empty function instead of `undefined`:

```
myCallback = function(){};
```

Alternately, you could check for the condition within the `click` handler:

```
var condition = true;
var myFunction = function() {
  if( !condition )
    return;
  // do something
}

$(".myClass").on("click", myFunction);

$(window).resize(function(){
  if(//certain conditions are met) {
    condition = false;
  }
  else {
    condition = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way which you tried didn't work as you didn't pass your callback physically, just a pointer to it. So doing

```
myCallback = undefined;
```

Doesn't clear your callback, it just changes pointer to undefined variable. jQuery saves information about your callback before you change the pointer. That's why it didn't work.

Consider refactoring to:

```
  let guardian = true;
  let clickHandler = function () {
    if (guardian) {
      /* your code */
    }
  };

  $(".class").on("click", clickHandler);

  $(window).resize( function () {
    if (/* certain conditions are met */) {
      guardian = false;
    } else {
      guardian = true;
    }
  });
```

In that case, we change guardian variable during resizing and check against it in our click handler. You don't have to on/off your callback handlers in such a case.

Answer (score -1):

It's certainly not pretty code, and steps should be taken to make it obvious to other developers (or future-you) that this callback may not be a callback later on, but jQuery's .on method will not try and run anything that equates (think `==`) to false.

Therefore, setting your callback to undefined will not error.